# Why VSCode recognize tsc for a project but not for another

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Within same computer same vscode, I get : "The term 'tsc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" on a project I copied partially from first one.

How is this possible whereas I don't get that error on original project ? I tried to fix by also copying task.json in .vscode but same.

Comment: no because the other is about a new project whereas I have already a project that works with typescript.

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII oh well maybe because I only made a partial copy so thanks.